# Igraph: Set minimum number of vertices to form Cluster

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, igraph

is in the R igraph package any way to set a minimum number of vertices to form a cluster when calling an cluster-command?

Looking up the "communities" help pages I found the parameter "no" but I actually could figure out how to use it.

In my case:

```
cl<- cluster_louvain(graph)
```

gives me some cluster with only 2 Genes involved. I want these to be assigned to other clusters to form clusters with at least 10 Genes.

Many thanks in advance!
Lea

Comment: Most algorithms do not allow setting a minimum cluster size. How about just ignoring smaller clusters?

Comment: But then I will ignore these genes - I would prefer that these get advised to another cluster

Comment: Which will make the quality of these clusters degrade a lot!

Comment: And for all I know from biology, there are good reasons to *not* cluster all genes. Some (most?) may not be currently active, only very few will be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for thinking about my problem :) 
That is indeed something I did not really take into account while attacking that problem !